# Getting wrong item image button clicked in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview that contains items. And each item has an image button. When an image button is clicked, i want to change it's image using the following code. The code does change the button clicked, but it also changes other items' images that are not clicked. Why this happens, and how to fix?

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }


        final ImageButton playButton = ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause));

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // In the log I get correct position of clicked item, but the image changes are wrong.
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked row-" + view.getTag().toString());
                ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);


            }
        });

        playButton.setTag(position);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You have to save the state imageview for each position. And then set the resource according to its state. Otherwise android will recycle the views and change its state

Comment: I tried it inside of onClick event, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the begining of your adapter

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> states = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

And in your onClick add this:

```
if(states.containsKey(position))
{
   states.put(position, !states.get(position));
   ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause)).setImageResource(states.get(position)?R.drawable.button_pause:R.drawable.button_play);
}
else
{
   states.put(position, true);
   ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
}
```

And before your return view add this:

```
if(states.containsKey(position) && states.get(position))
   ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
else
   ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
```

Comment: One problem is that variable position is accesed from within inner class

Comment: Well, change it to final `public View getView(final int position,(...)`

Comment: Ok, but now i do not see the changes unless i scroll down and scroll up again.